# QTextEdit and custom scrolling - PageDown/PageUp

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, qtextedit, qabstractslider

I'm trying to implement a custom scrolling behavior in a [QTextEdit](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtextedit.html) control. It seems to be working but I'm having problems with the PageDown/PageUp key press: I'm controlling the scrolling behavior through the [actionTriggered](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qabstractslider.html#actionTriggered) signal since the documentation states:

> When the signal is emitted, the sliderPosition has been adjusted
>   according to the action, but the value has not yet been propagated
>   (meaning the valueChanged() signal was not yet emitted), and the
>   visual display has not been updated. In slots connected to this signal
>   you can thus safely adjust any action by calling setSliderPosition()
>   yourself, based on both the action and the slider's value.

and starting a QTimer with the `sliderPosition` I need to reach from there (e.g. I'm incrementing each time `value()` to reach `sliderPosition`). Unfortunately every time I press a PageUp/PageDown key there's also another [setValue](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qabstractslider.html#value-prop)() function call **triggered by the caret which gets moved by the PageUp/PageDown key** which moves automatically the scrollbar value to the end of the animation.

The call stack shows:

```
QAbstractSlider::setValue(int)
??
QMetaObject::activate(QObject*, int, int, void**)   
QWidgetTextControl::visibilityRequest(QRectF const&)    
QWidgetTextControl::ensureCursorVisible()  <--
QWidgetTextControl::setTextCursor(QTextCursor const&)   <--
QTextEdit::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent*)
QWidget::event(QEvent*)
QFrame::event(QEvent*)
QAbstractScrollArea::event(QEvent*)
QTextEdit::event(QEvent*)
QApplicationPrivate::notify_helper(QObject*, QEvent*)
QApplication::notify(QObject*, QEvent*)
QCoreApplication::notifyInternal(QObject*, QEvent*)
...
```

I have no idea of how to prevent the caret from issuing that `QAbstractSlider::SetValue()` call when the caret is moved due to the PageUp/PageDown key press.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried to `QObject::disconnect` the SetValue signal?

Comment: It couldn't work Thomas because I was relying on the `setValue()` method myself

Comment: Maybe i misunderstood, but i did not mean to disconnect `setValue()` entirely, just the specific connection `disconnect(receiver, SLOT(setValue...), unwanted_sender, SIGNAL(...))`, which should leave you all options to use setValue - possibly by a new connection you install. Nevertheless, since it works now ... ;)

Comment: Oh now I got it, sorry :) Yes, that could have worked as well I suppose. It's another way of doing it and quite creative I'd say. If you post an answer with that, I'll accept it (my solution is more involved and I had to radically change the logic behind).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OKay, so just use

```
disconnect(receiver, SLOT(setValue...), unwanted_sender, SIGNAL(...))
```

to break the specific unwanted connection.

Answer (score 0):

After a day of research I found the solution thanks to *PapierKorb*:

- I used [QPropertyAnimation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qpropertyanimation.html) instead of a hand-made `QTimer` handling on the `value` property
- I installed a key event filter for the parent control in order to catch PageDown/PageUp events ([installEventFilter](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qobject.html#installEventFilter)) and had the ScrollBar handle all the scrolling behavior. At the end of the animation I manually moved the cursor to the new position without sending any `setValue` signals